# Dynamically created fields and buttons are not clickable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a simple signin screen. I created a couple of dynamic fields, attached a listener to the buttons, but I can't tap on the elements to start typing my username and password. If I press TAB, the focus goes into the inputs but I can't use the click. What am i doing wrong?

See code and screenshot below. The area highlighted in red is unclickable, and i have the accessibility inspector on. It never shows any of my elements.

```
@interface PRLoginController() <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) UIView *inputView;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *loginButton;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *cancelButton;
- (void)doLogin;
- (void)doCancel;

- (void)initializeUserInput;

+ (UIViewController *)getTopViewController;

@end


@implementation PRLoginController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Login";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    [self initializeUserInput];
}


- (void)initializeUserInput {

    UIView *inputView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    inputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    CGFloat inputViewMargin = 50.0;
    CGFloat inputElementTopMargin = 20.0;

    [self.view addSubview:inputView];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:inputViewMargin],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:-inputViewMargin]
                                ]];

    _inputView = inputView;

    CGFloat textFieldHeight = 30.0;

    UITextField *topTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    topTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [inputView addSubview:topTextField];
    [inputView addConstraints:@[
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:textFieldHeight],
                                ]];

    UITextField *bottomTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    bottomTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [inputView addSubview:bottomTextField];
    [inputView addConstraints:@[
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:topTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:inputElementTopMargin],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:textFieldHeight]
                                ]];

    topTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    bottomTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    topTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    bottomTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

    topTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    bottomTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    topTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    bottomTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

    topTextField.delegate = self;
    bottomTextField.delegate = self;

    topTextField.placeholder = @"Username";
    bottomTextField.placeholder = @"Password";

    _usernameTextField = topTextField;
    _passwordTextField = bottomTextField;

    UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    leftButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [inputView addSubview:leftButton];
    [inputView addConstraints:@[
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:150],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:-5.0],
                                ]];

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rightButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [inputView addSubview:rightButton];
    [inputView addConstraints:@[
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:150],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0],
                                [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:5.0],
                                ]];

    leftButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    rightButton.backgroundColor = leftButton.backgroundColor;

    leftButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    rightButton.layer.cornerRadius = leftButton.layer.cornerRadius;


    [leftButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doCancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _loginButton = leftButton;
    _cancelButton = rightButton;

}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

I have removed the gesture recognizer but that didn't help. Clicking on the ui doesn't do anything. I'm not particularly interested on that handler, it was copied from a different view, but removing it didn't help either.

Comment: Why do you have a tap gesture recognizer on the root view?

Comment: @NRitH The tap recogniser appears to be to dismiss the keyboard on a tap out of the textfields. @caiocpricci2 can you add a log in the recognisers handler, I imagine it is intercepting the touches and not allowing the through to the text fields. Tap on the text field and see if the tap recogniser log is fired. Also you don't need to add `inputView` and set it's constraints twice.

Comment: Try removing the tap recogniser and see if you then get desired behaviour with the text fields... If so we can look at the `UIGestureRecignizerDelegate` to solve it properly.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen thanks for the tip, i have removed the recognizer and the double setup of inputView, but that didn't help either. Updated the code to match my current controller.

Comment: @caiocpricci2 Hmm, the plot thickens... Could you have a look for the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in Xcode (on top of the debug area, just to the right of the "step up" action) and activate that to look at the view hierarchy here. If possible can you rotate that sideways so we can see the view stack and post a screen shot of that? (sorry for all the requests)

Comment: @GeorgeGreen thanks for the suggestion, apologies, i'm fairly new to iOS dev. Attached what looks like the view hierarchy.

Comment: @caiocpricci2 Perfect, now if you click and drag sideways on that, it will show a side view where we can see the layering of all the views, any chance you could try that too?

Comment: @caiocpricci2 Actually, nvm, I can see what I need in the tree on the left :)

Comment: Aha, can you check the frame of `inputView` at runtime, I suspect it may have 0 height, causing all touches to fall outside of it's bounds.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen Spot on. I removed the inputView and the click worked. If you can put how to get that inputView to actually have a height as an answer i'll accept it so other people can benefit from this too! Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problemo .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `inputView` may be incorrectly sized causing all touches to fall outside of it's bounds, and therefore not get passed to subviews. Try adding these constraints

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:-inputViewMargin],
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-inputViewMargin]
```

to have the `inputView` vertically fill it's container. You seem to already be constraining the leading and trailing (left and right edges) but need to also do the top and bottom.